# recyclerView load more data which shortest and easy ways?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to load more data to show recycle view after 10 data loads. example below. I'm tired to find it. I can't understand the solution. I want an easy solution.

Example: [image]

**CommentPost.java**

```
 public void showData(){
    //view Comment
    progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(CommentPost.this);
    progressDoalog.setMessage("Loading....");
    progressDoalog.show();
    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    Call<List<Comments>> call = service.getComment(audioPath);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Comments>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Comments>> call, Response<List<Comments>> response) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            generateDataList(response.body());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Comments>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(CommentPost.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
/*Method to generate List of data using RecyclerView with custom adapter*/
private void generateDataList(List<Comments> CommentsList) {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new CommentAdapter(this,CommentsList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(CommentPost.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //latest message
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
@SuppressLint("RecyclerView")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getComment());
    holder.txttime.setText(dataList.get(position).getUpdated_at());
    holder.userNametitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getuser_name());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "" + dataList.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to read about DiffUtil & Paging APIs

Comment: I can't understand. I want to proper example and solution.

Comment: Google "RecyclerView Pagination Android", you don't give us what your code looks like, so it isn't easy to provide you with real tips.

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/swlh/paging3-recyclerview-pagination-made-easy-333c7dfa8797) out

Comment: I'm add example code. please check it. @Aiman Alyosofi

Answer (score 1):

First thing the function `generateDataList` must call first time only
So I'm going to call it from the `onCreat`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     ...
     generateDataList();
}
private void generateDataList() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new CommentAdapter(this,new ArrayList<>());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(CommentPost.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

You can create your layout like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nestedSV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
  
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
          
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            tools:listitem="@layout/user_rv_item" />
          
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
      
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And we going to set the scroll listener for `NestedScrollView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    nestedSV = findViewById(R.id.nestedSV);
    nestedSV.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            // When the Scroll of NestedScrollView in bottom
            if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                // show the progressbar and then get more data to the recyclerview
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showData();
            }
        }
    });
    generateDataList();
}
```

And We going to change `showData()`:

```
public void showData(){
    Call<List<Comments>> call = service.getComment(audioPath);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Comments>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Comments>> call, Response<List<Comments>> response) {
            // here instead of generateDataList we going to add the data with addToList
            addToList(response.body());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Comments>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(CommentPost.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


private void addToList(List<Comments> commentsList) {
     // this is add commentsList data to the adapter list
     adapter. dataList.addAll(commentsList);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: adapter.getList()   getlist error. what can i do?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getList' in 'CommentAdapter'   @Animan Alyosofi

Comment: this return the 'dataList' inside the adapter. ```public List<Comments> getList(){return dataList;}```

Comment: I don't understand brother. Please more code?

Comment: Sorry if this makes you confused, this just includes the important parts only for you to get the idea and what's wrong in your code, So you should try to match these codes according to what you did before.

Comment: Ok, I will try to edit my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a library for that purpose which is `paging` library, you can know how it works [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) from google documentation, or you can follow this [video](https://youtu.be/CKuVM2yPgPw) where you will learn how to use paging library to achieve the result that you want.